# Datatables/multi-select component - Select Filter "alphabretic" order

Tags: datatables, multi-select

I hope you might help me.

There is any way to order the select filters?

> like = a,b,c,d,e.. and not = a,e,f,v,d...

Link to a demo link to a demo - https://jsfiddle.net/omarcho/kad40x9o/

With `"order": [[2, 'asc']]`, I can order 1 column but is I use:

`"order": [[ 0, 'asc' ], [ 1, 'asc' ]]` OR `order": [[2,3,4,5,6, 'asc']],` doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Answers

Answer (score 0):

solved.

Added sort() to .each(function (value)

In multiselect.js